# C#/Win32: WNDPROC is invoked after being garbage-collected

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm writing a cross-platform emulator frontend using Eto.Forms in C#. The emulator backend requires a native window to display its output to, and thus, I need to write native controls wrapping said native windows.

To create a WinAPI window, I need to create and register a window class, which I do like this (imports and static imports removed for clarity):

```cs
    static unsafe Win32SubWindow()
    {
        _refWndProc = WindowProc;

        fixed (char* pWindowClass = WINDOW_CLASS)
        {
            WNDCLASSEXW wndClass = new()
            {
                cbSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf<WNDCLASSEXW>(),
                style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
                lpfnWndProc = _refWndProc,
                cbClsExtra = 0,
                cbWndExtra = 0,
                hInstance = CurrentHInstanceRaw,
                hIcon = HICON.Null,
                hCursor = LoadCursor(HINSTANCE.Null, IDC_ARROW),
                hbrBackground = HBRUSH.Null,
                lpszMenuName = null,
                lpszClassName = pWindowClass,
                hIconSm = HICON.Null
            };

            RegisterClassEx(in wndClass);
        }
    }

    internal static readonly WNDPROC _refWndProc;
```

The `_refWndProc` variable should keep the delegate alive until the program ends, but I'm met with this error when I close my window:

```
Process terminated. A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'M64RPFW.Wpf!Windows.Win32.UI.WindowsAndMessaging.WNDPROC::Invoke'.
Repeat 3 times:
--------------------------------
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
--------------------------------
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at Eto.Wpf.Forms.ApplicationHandler.Run()
   at Eto.Forms.Application.Run()
   at M64PRR.Wpf.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

What could cause `Win32SubWindow._refWndProc` to be garbage-collected while it is still in use? Other SO questions I've found have been solved by maintaining a reference to the delegate.

Comment: Have you tried `GC.KeepAlive` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.keepalive?view=net-7.0. The compiler can put hunts to the runtime saying "this variable is still in scope but is no longer referenced by the code". That makes the object it references eligible for collection. A call to `KeepAlive` removes that possibility

Comment: Are you sure the exception matches the code and these variables? Do you have a complete reproducing sample code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Flydog57 I've tried using `GCHandle.Alloc` without calling `GCHandle::Free`. This should in theory keep the object alive for an indefinite period of time. That failed as well.

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't have an MRE. However, the message relates to WNDPROC, and this is the only instance of WNDPROC in my

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The error was caused by a different instance of `WNDPROC` than the one mentioned here. My application also uses a helper window to help initialize OpenGL, and moving *that* window's `WNDPROC` to a variable solved the issue.